# Issue on Swift Mac and CloudKit, were app runs then immediately crashes

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, crash, cloudkit

Currently, my team at the moment is having an issue where we cannot run an app on Mac. The app has been converted to Mac from iOS and uses CloudKit. The issue resulted after adding to the Entitlements file.

Every time we run the application from Xcode, Xcode immediately reports that the app "finished running successfully," though the app never launches. Cleaning the build folder does not resolve this issue.

Entitlements File
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue was, we didn't notice a little symbol in the com.apple.developer.icloud-containter (the one at the bottom). This led to it not running because of this symbol. We didn't notice because the symbol was at the end. This was a major oof.

The entitlements key was listed as `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment - 2` rather than `com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment`.